# Is there a way for Jenkins to read and xml file via a web service call and show it in the Jenkins web UI

Tags: xml, api, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

As the title present, is there a way for Jenkins to read an xml file and have it show in the Jenkins web UI.

Currently I'm building a plugin in Jenkins that communicates one of our products using restful api web service call. That part is finished (or close to it at least). Now what I need to do is to get a report from our product and present it in Jenkins. The report will be an XML file format. Getting the xml report is simple (via web service call) but presenting or showing it in Jenkins is the tricky part. Any help I on how to do this is really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins provide a `visible` folder named `userContent` under $JENKINS_HOME directory. You can throw any file into this folder then access it from the web UI.

In your case, just try to put your xml file into `userContent` folder then access it from the url http://your-jenkins-server-url/userContent/foo.xml

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A http link to an xml file in workspace will simply display it in the client's browser.